# Python cmd shell: handling undefined commands

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a shell that must be able to take an *unlimited* number of commands.  I can't figure out from the docs (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cmd.html) which say:

> Cmd.default(line) Method called on an input line when the command
>   prefix is not recognized. If this method is not overridden, it prints
>   an error message and returns.

I must be writing the default() method incorrectly?

I've tried this:

```
import cmd

class MyShell(cmd.Cmd):

    def default():
        print('you entered this unknown command: ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyShell().cmdloop()
```

but get this (when I enter 'hi' in the shell):

```
(Cmd) hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/anaconda/lib/python3.6/cmd.py", line 214, in onecmd
    func = getattr(self, 'do_' + cmd)
AttributeError: 'MyShell' object has no attribute 'do_hi'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitmessage_shell.py", line 9, in <module>
    MyShell().cmdloop()
  File "/Users/david/anaconda/lib/python3.6/cmd.py", line 138, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "/Users/david/anaconda/lib/python3.6/cmd.py", line 216, in onecmd
    return self.default(line)
TypeError: default() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Comment: `def default():` => `def default(self,line):`

Comment: and (maybe) define `def do_hi(self)` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def default():
    print('you entered this unknown command: ')
```

that doesn't work in a class. You need at least the object argument (`self`), or make the method static/class using `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` decorators (but not very convenient, you may need the object state at some point)

Moreover, the parent class seems to pass the line, so now you need 2 arguments:

```
def default(self,line):
    print('you entered this unknown command: ',line)
```

Comment: Thanks that was it, I didn't have the right parameters in my various attempts at writing default().  I can't find this documented properly with an example anywhere.